# Storing files that available to different projects in solution .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have one solution with 2 .NET MVC projects and some class library projects. Also I have some xml files. I need to put these xml files in one place and have access to them from these 2 .NET MVC projects. These files need also be published.
Can I create App_Data folder in class library project and put these xml files there and use them? Or App_Data folder just related to .NET MVC projects?

How can I resolve my issue?

Comment: what about virtual directory ?  create virtual directory from both project hosts and give the shared files path, or else you can use Server.MapPath() method to find his Shared folder

Comment: I want to store xml files inside my solution

Comment: Why do you need to store xml files inside your solution ? You only need its content right ?? Or if its mandatory then use a class library and share that in both projects

Comment: I just want to find simple solution as possible. Could you give me example how can I use class library to resolve it? And also creating of virtual directory?

Comment: Put your library or core code into one project, then reference that project in both solutions. Just right click and add project is enough here. Your common code should be inside your class library.

Comment: So, I select class library project that has reference to both MVC projects in my single solution. Then how can I get path to that file (xml) and ensure xml files are deployed and available on server?

Comment: A class library is compiled to a dll. The files are not copied along. Unless "embedded resource" is an option - then they will be compiled *into* the assembly (you cannot edit them on the server and you need a different way to read them)

Comment: if both projects are in same solution then create some shared folder and add your xl files over there

Answer (score 0):

If your two MVC projects are host on same sever, you can store these xml files anywhere you want.

By adding a appSetting key to store the physical path of these xml files folder into web.config file for these two MVC project.

Then your program just read these files by get the path from the web.config file.

Comment: So,
I put in web.config of both projects setting with "~/AppData/1.xml" and put 1.xml file to App_Data of project 1. Will it work when I launch project 2 and want to download 1.xml file?

Comment: If you have more than one files,  do like this  <add key="XMLFileFolder" value="C:\Projects\XMLFolder" />, put all files into that folder,  ideally this folder doesn't matter with any project, any project can read file from that specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how you plan to use your xml files, but if I understand you correctly you just want that the file is published to the output directory, that will mean that it will be accessible to any libraries/projects that are running.

So if you put your xml library in a common project that you say you have then you can edit properties of that xml file and set e.g. Build Action to Content or Copy To Output directory to Always (depending on how you do the publish it would probably behave a bit differently).

Then this file should appear in both bin folders.

Alternatively if this does not work, you can create a shortcut to the same file from both projects. You can do this by clicking "add existing item", then click on a triangle next to `Add` button and in the menu you can chose `add as a link`

Answer (score 0):

*Step 1.* Create shared folder (that does not included into your projects) and copy all shared files there. 
*Step 2.* Change **.csproj** file and describe pre-build action, that just will copy all needed files from shared folder into your project. Something like this:

```
<Target Name="CodeAnalysisRuleset" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" Condition="$(ConfigurationName) == Debug">
    <Exec Command="xcopy /Y &quot;$(SolutionDir)\SharedCodingRules\codeAnalysis.ruleset&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

*Step 3.* Explicitly include new files into your project (again change you .csproj file)

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="stylecop.json" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <AdditionalFiles Include="stylecop.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After those 3 steps you will be able use shared files (configurations, rullsets etc.) in differnt projects.