# Configuring multiple web.config files

Tags: c#, web-services, web-config

At the moment I have a solution with multiple projects, 2 of those are wcf services with their own web.config files. Everything worked well but stopped working at existing code after I added some new values to one of the web.config files. After some research I found out the service did not refer to his old web.config (his own) but to the other one. My solution to the problem: I add the key settings to the other webconfig aswell so they both have the same appsettings. This worked but as you might understand i am not satisfied with this problem. There is no certainty it will magically switch from file again and i need to make sure both files equals all the time.

Is it possible i use one web.config file or 1 appSettings block for 2 different projects? They both use the same values

Comment: if first Project internally refers the second project, means both projects executes in same process then the launching project Web.Config file will be used. and uses of 1 Web.Config file for two project is not possible if they they in two seperate process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **pre-build action** and copy *web.config* from shared folder in to all projects will be workable for you. 
Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54925165/3434393